# PHP Code generator based on templates

Tags: php, regex, code-generation, scaffolding

I want to generate the code based on the templates.

Suppose in `/Templates` I have files structured as:

```
/Templates
```

- Vendor/Plugin/config.xml
- Vendor/Plugin/Model/Plugin.php
- Vendor/Plugin/View/plugin.phtml

And say the files have the following contents(variables enclosed with `{{ }}` needs to be parsed):

*Vendor/Plugin/config.xml:*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <module>{{Vendor}}/{{Plugin}}</module>
    <version>{{Version}}</version>

    {{if $HasTable}}
    <database>
        <table>{{TableName}}</table>
        <pk>{{PrimaryKey}}</pk>
        <fields>
            {{foreach $Fields}}
            <field>
                <name>{{Fields.Name}}</name>
                <label>{{Fields.Label}}</label>
                <type>{{Fields.Type}}</type>
            </field>
            {{/foreach}}
        </fields>
    </database>
    {{/if}}

</config>
```

*Vendor/Plugin/Model/Plugin.php:*

```
<?php

/**
 * @category {{Vendor}}_{{Plugin}}
 * @author  {{Author}}
 */
class {{Vendor}}_{{Plugin}}_Model_{{Plugin}} extends Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    {{if $HasTable}}
    public function setTable()
    {
        $this->_tableName = '{{TableName}}';
    }
    public function setPrimaryKey()
    {
        $this->_primaryKey = '{{PrimaryKey}}';
    }
    public function setFields()
    {
        $this->_fields = Core::Config('database/table/fields');
    }
    {{/if}}
}
```

*Vendor/Plugin/View/plugin.phtml:*

```
{{TableName}} Rows
<table>
    <tr>
        {{foreach $Fields}}
            <th>{{$Fields.Label}}</th>
        {{/foreach}}
    </tr>

    <?php foreach ($data as $_data) ?>
        <tr>
            {{foreach $Fields}}
                <td><?php echo $_data['{{$Fields.Name}}'] ?></td>
            {{/foreach}}
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

</table>
```

**How the code generator should work?**

1> A GUI Form which will let users to add at least following fields

Vendor:
Plugin:
Version:
Author:

Has Tables?:
If selected to yes, it will allow users to add more fields like table name, it's fields etc.

2> On submitting the form, it generates the code from /Templates folder to some directory
Logic can be:
Preparing the variables to fed into the CoreGenerator (class to be developed), which will read all the template files and re-generates them by parsing those variables.

Expected output from `/Template` will be:
(Suppose if we have following valures from user input

```
Vendor: Foo
Plugin: Bar
Version: 1.0.0
Author: John Doe <john.doe@example.com>
Has Tables?: Yes
Table Name: blog
Primary Key: blog_id
Fields:
+ Name: title, Label: Title, Type: Text
+ Name: status, Label: Status, Type:Int
...
```

)

```
/Generated
```

- Foo/Bar/config.xml
- Foo/Bar/Model/Bar.php
- Foo/Bar/View/bar.phtml <- note the case sensitivty)

**Generated Contents:**

*Foo/Bar/config.xml:*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <module>Foo/Bar</module>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <database>
        <table>blog</table>
        <pk>blog_id</pk>
        <fields>

            <field>
                <name>title</name>
                <label>Title</label>
                <type>Text</type>
            </field>
            <field>
                <name>status</name>
                <label>Status</label>
                <type>Int</type>
            </field>
            <!--... -->

        </fields>
    </database>

</config>
```

*Foo/Bar/Model/Bar.php:*

```
<?php

/**
 * @category Foo_Bar
 * @author  John Doe <john.doe@example.com>
 */
class Foo_Bar_Model_Bar extends Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }


    public function setTable()
    {
        $this->_tableName = 'blog';
    }
    public function setPrimaryKey()
    {
        $this->_primaryKey = 'blog_id';
    }
    public function setFields()
    {
        $this->_fields = Core::Config('database/table/fields');
    }

}
```

*Foo/Bar/View/bar.phtml:*

```
blog Rows
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>

    <?php foreach ($data as $_data) ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $_data['title'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $_data['status'] ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

</table>
```

So my main concern will be for the Code Generator class/library which will collect placeholder values from user input, read all those files from `/Templates` folder and regenerate them after parsing those variables (simple, conditional, loop etc.) to `/Generated` folder.

Any insights on this, how should I start with? any rough idea, solutions & references are highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is anyone having a code generator based on Symfony's twig template? Please share

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you use instead a gui interface a cli interface. Because in that way is more easily customizable.

As a reference you can use Yeoman a large scaffold tool, well documented, that can help you to build a generator with less efforts.
http://yeoman.io/

For inspiration, take a look at this generator demo:
https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack

Comment: I have been looking into this before. The reason I left is I wanted a GUI based so that I can generate it from anywhere (from shared hosting etc.) unlike Yeoman.

Comment: May you can generate in your own and then deploy it later.

Comment: I am thinking of using #twig templating for the purpose.